# Is there a way to use Conditional Formatting on a row based on values in a single column?

Tags: microsoft-excel, formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Conditional formatting to highlight the whole row](https://superuser.com/questions/448261/conditional-formatting-to-highlight-the-whole-row)

I have a sheet to be conditionally formatted. I want to format the whole row based on key text. Is it possible?

Comment: I *think* you're asking whether it's possible to format an entire row, if one of the *cells* is containing that text. Yes you can, with a macro. You can do almost anything with a macro. Create a button on the sheet, and program it to iterate through each row and then cell in the sheet for the text value. Format the row accordingly.

Comment: -1 for recommending someone iterate though every cell on a sheet.  Bad before excel 2007, much worse now.  Assuming they coded it correctly, most people would assume their excel crashed if they ran it.

Comment: I stand by the suggestion. My own code searches each row and then each cell in the row (if it finds a hit) - with screen refresh off until it's done, I could find and format text on a 25MB file in under 30 seconds: Windows XP Pro, Core 2 Duo, 2GB RAM. But thanks anyway, Dave.

Comment: Duplicate of later, but clearer question: http://superuser.com/q/448261/76571

Comment: See http://meta.superuser.com/q/5185/76571

Answer (score 6):

OK, I think I got your point. You want to highlight the complete row if only 1 cell of that row matches a value, right?

Put the value you want to match in a cell somewhere (for my example, A1).
Select the row(s) where you want to have the conditional formatting.
In the Home section of the Ribbon, go to Conditional Formatting, then select New Rule.

In the new Formatting Rule windows, select "Use a formula to determine which cells to format".
In the field "Format values where the formula is true", enter "*=IF(MATCH(**$A$1**;**$13:$13**;0)>0;TRUE;FALSE)*". Change the **$A$1** with the cell address where you put the value you want to match, eventually on another sheet. Change the **$13:$13** (meaning here row 13) with the row you want to highlight. It works also for any range of cells (B4:C8 for instance).

Click the Format... button to select how you want to highlight the rows (border, fill, font, ...).

I tested it and it works (in Excel 2007). No need for a macro ;-) .

**Edit**:

You can skip storing the value to match in a cell (A1) and hardcode it directly in the formula if you know the value won't change: *=IF(MATCH(**25**;$13:$13;0)>0;TRUE;FALSE*

Comment: Or your method would work :-).

Comment: So that's what he meant. Good answer :). +1

Comment: I've tried a few minutes ago, but I couldn't success...I got this result: Only one cell, containing the key value formatted. May I did Wrong?

Comment: =IF(MATCH($D$16;$16:$16;0)>0;TRUE;FALSE) my code

Comment: The first argument of MATCH is the value with which you want to match the row. It ($D$16) must not be in the same row ($16:$16) than the row you want to highlight of course, as this will always work and always highlight the row.

Comment: Bear in mind that applying CF toa row does not scale very well, so if you have a hundred rows you have 25,500 CF cells in 2003, and a mighty 1,638,400 CF cells in 2007/2010.  This can make the workbook very sluggish.

Comment: This will make it sluggish. It will also increase its size. It would be better if only some cells are selected, not the whole row.

Answer (score 4):

This is being way over analyzed = highlight the columns that are not the columns that hold the value you want identified & enter the following formula in the conditional formatting:

=AND($D1="cat")

the above formula is assuming the value you are using as the identifier is in column d and that the value is cat.

so using this formula as the conditional formatting of columns A,B,&C, would make the format apply if the value of Column D is the word "cat" (and no, it does not highlight row 4 if cell D1 has "cat" in it, but it WILL highlight row 4 if D4 has "cat" in it).

Comment: You don't need the AND.  =$D1="cat" is sufficient

Answer (score 3):

Select the cells (or row) you want, go to **Format** -> **Conditional Formatting...** and add the rules you want. When you input anything in the cells, the formatting will be done automatically.

Comment: Only in Excel 2007. The OP didn't specify the version of Excel (s)he uses.

Comment: It works in Excel 2003. I just tested it right now.

Comment: Ok, my bad. Sorry.

Comment: No problem; maybe in Excel 2007 this option is more advanced. I haven't really used it.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure the existing answers are as clear as they could be...

Excel XP/2002/2003

1. Select the row(s) you wish the formatting to apply to
2. Click Format>>Conditional Formatting
3. Change Condition 1 to "Formula is"
4. Enter formula, referencing only the test cell **but with an absolute reference ($) on the column component and the top row in your selection as the row**, e.g. `=IF($C4>100,True,False)` if you have rows 4+ selected and want to change the entire row if the cell in the fourth column, C, is over 100
5. Set your format in the normal way

Excel knows that you want to format the row and, due to the relative row reference, will apply this to each cell in each row that you have selected.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I've found a simple solution and will share with You.

Writing a formula like this:
=$H1="Open" or 1,2 then specify the range from Applies to:$1 to $1048576
here is the H1 contains the conditional value.

Thanks for every effort and every comment...