# EXCEL: How to conditional format a thick bottom border to an entire row based on one column value?

Tags: microsoft-excel, border, conditional-formatting

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Excel conditional formatting to highlight entire row if one date is not equal to another date in that row](https://superuser.com/questions/368087/excel-conditional-formatting-to-highlight-entire-row-if-one-date-is-not-equal-to)

I have the following rows...

```
1   AA     12  13   4   7
1   A      12  13   5   2
1   A      12  14   5   2
1   AAA    1   15   3   1
2   AAA    1   15   3   1
2   AA     3   44   5   19
2   A      R   4    33  87
3   AA     3   3R   55  77
```

And I'm wanting to learn how to do conditional formatting so that if the left most column changes in value I can add a thick bottom border to the entire row.  So for instance it would appear like this...

```
1   AA     12  13   4   7
1   A      12  13   5   2
1   A      12  14   5   2
1   AAA    1   15   3   1
-------------------------
2   AAA    1   15   3   1
2   AA     3   44   5   19
2   A      R   4    33  87
-------------------------
3   AA     3   3R   55  77
```

and so on...

I was able to get it to work, but only for the first column and not format the entire row.
Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to anchor the column references in the formula for the conditional format.

Assuming that your data range begins in `A1`, you would set a conditional format on the range `A1:F1` with a criterion formula `$A1<>$A2` and your chosen format.

Then, you would copy the formatting of the row down the range (using **Paste Special Format**).

Comment: Thanks! For the answer still new to excel! The $'s were what I was missing.

Comment: This was a great, answer, but I forgot that a formula in excel always starts with `=` - so I eventually realised I could: select the whole block and add conditional formatting, I just needed to make sure the box contained: `=$A1<>$A2` :)

Comment: How do you get a thick bottom border? Conditional formatting only allows a thin border.

Answer (score 2):

Supposing your top-left cell is A1, select all the data **starting at A1** and then use this formula:

```
=$A1<>$A2
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is some VBA that will perform what you are looking for.

```
Sub LineSep()

'   Start Location 1 lower than first range with value
Range("A2").Select

Do
    If ActiveCell.Offset(-1, 0).Value = ActiveCell.Value Then
    ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
        Else:
        Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlToRight)).Select
        With Selection.Borders(xlEdgeTop)
            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
            .ColorIndex = 0
            .TintAndShade = 0
            .Weight = xlMedium
        End With
        ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
    End If

Loop Until ActiveCell.Value = ""

End Sub
```

Comment: For other VBA code to perform this function, see https://www.mrexcel.com/forum/excel-questions/749698-automatically-adding-border-line-after-change-value-column.html#post3683193