# Conditional formatting to highlight the whole row

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function, conditional-formatting

I would like to highlight the whole row 5 if `J5="T"`.

I used to do it with the old Excel, the 2010 conditional formatting ignores it. So my rule is like this and it does not work. I used the formula `$J$20="T"`, apply to `A5:ZZ5`, or `$5:$5` — nothing works.

It is supposed to change the format if the result of the formula is true, so if it is anything else than a "T" it should not highlight/change the format.

The formula was simple and it worked before, now it can not understand it.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a way to use Conditional Formatting on a row based on values in a single column?](http://superuser.com/questions/38885/is-there-a-way-to-use-conditional-formatting-on-a-row-based-on-values-in-a-singl)

Answer (score 9):

If your **Applies to** field is set to `A5:ZZ5` (or `$5:$5` to highlight the entire row), your formula should be

```
=$J5="T"
```

**Note where the `$` is placed.**

In my example below, my formula is set to `=$J1="T"` and my **Applies to** field is set to `$A$1:$Z$6`.

[image]