# Excel: Different background colors on condition

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, conditional-formatting

### The problem

I have a Excel sheet that contains a status column.

```
Number  Status              Name
-------------------------------------
     1  not implemented     feature 1
     2  completed           feature 2
     3  new                 feature 3
     4  open                feature 4
```

I want each **row** have a different background color depending on the cell value of column `status`.

### My attempt

I tried chosing *conditional formatting->new rule*. This dialog pops up

[image: conditional formatting dialog]

but I can't find a setting that both applies to the complete row and let my define a rule for different colors depending on a specific cell value.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Conditional formatting to highlight the whole row](http://superuser.com/questions/448261/conditional-formatting-to-highlight-the-whole-row)

Comment: @Excellll: The duplicate you refer too - does this work with multiple conditions as well and not just a single true/false condition. I need multiple colors.

Comment: You have to a set up a rule for each value/color combination. Each rule should be like what's described in the linked duplicate.

Comment: The answer in the duplicate question seems to be too advanced for me. I don't know about that dialogs they are talking about

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Select all cells of your sheet
- Open *conditional formatting -> new rule*
- Choose the last entry in the list.
- Define your cell value with leading `$`. Only the column name is important, the row can be random. For instance `=$B1="not implemented"`
- Choose a color for this setting by selecting "format"
- For each color define a seperarte rule

[image: conditional formatting dialog]

Comment: If this answers your question, don't forget to mark it as the accepted answer, by clicking on the checkmark on the left side of the question.